# How to map bluetooth device to audio device in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I can find all bluetooth devices with `await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true))` or audio devices with `await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector())`.

How I can map bluetooth device to audio device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to map bluetooth device to audio device in UWP?

Currently, UWP does not provide api that could detect paired Bluetooth audio device. But you could detect each type device separately then compare with device name. Please note we could not compare with device id, because Bluetooth paired device is `AssociationEndpoint` kind and the audio is `DeviceInterface` kind.